# Запись онлайн трансляции c разбиением на куски

Tags: python, cmd, streaming

Необходимо выполнить запись онлайн трансляции.

С разбиением по времени или по размеру файла, т.е записывать трансляцию и разбивать ее "на ходу" на куски, чтобы сразу начать монтировать без ожидания конца стрима.

На данный момент существует несколько библиотек для этой задачи:

1. Youtube-dl (Заброшен)
2. Livestreamer (Заброшен)
3. Streamlink   (Поддерживается)

Проблема онлайн-трансляций - непостоянное количество кадров (записываются игры), что не позволяет нормально монтировать в Sony Vegas или Adobe Premiere (идет рассинхрон звука и видео)(Хоть и в последних версий Adobe Premiere сделали поддержку переменного количества кадров, но оно работает так убого, либо не работает вовсе)

До этого пытался решить эту задачу, использовав youtube-dl + ffmpeg рендеринг в постоянное количество кадров на ходу, но это грузило мой ноутбук (i7, 8 потоков по 2,4 Gz) до 100%, что не позволяло использовать монтирование параллельно с записью предыдущих участков.

Эту задачу я отложил до лучших времен.

Сейчас решил вернуться, использовав streamlink.

Пока пробую без рендеринга в постоянное количество кадров. Необходимо реализовать разделение видео на куски (по времени или размеру файла).
Но я не знаю как это реализовать.

Можно конечно на Python запускать файл bat, где запускается streamlink, и в Python проверять прошедшее время, а по окончанию процесса вырубать процесс и начинать занова. Проблема тут в том, что streamlink запускается довольно долго, и за это время на трансляции пройдет несколько секунд, что не подходит.

А из возможностей streamlink, это:

```
--hls-start-offset [HH:]MM:SS - Время, которое нужно пропустить с начала потока. Для потоков в реальном времени это отрицательное смещение от конца потока (перемотка назад).

--hls-duration [HH:]MM:SS - Ограничить продолжительность воспроизведения, полезно для просмотра сегментов потока. Фактическая продолжительность может быть немного больше, поскольку она округляется до ближайшего сегмента HLS.

По умолчанию: не ограничено .
```

Я воспользовался второй командной и написал cmd - скрипт

```
:loop
set day=%DATE:~0,2%
set month=%DATE:~3,2%
set year=%DATE:~6,4%

set hour=%TIME:~0,2%
set minute=%TIME:~3,2%
set second=%TIME:~6,2%

set YYYYMMDD=%hour%_%minute%_%second%_%day%_%month%_%year%


streamlink --hls-live-edge 99999 --hls-segment-threads 10 --ringbuffer-size 1024M --hls-duration 00:05:00 -o %YYYYMMDD%.ts https://www.twitch.tv/makatao best


goto loop
```

Но к сожалению разрыв ну очень большой. Причем если я указал в видео 5 минут, то следующее начнется не через 5 минут и больше, а меньше 5. Потому будет приходится синхронизировать разные видео между собой по какому то моменту, что тоже не удобно

Есть у кого какие предложения? (Канал выбрал первый попавшийся)

Мой код, который грузил CPU под 100%

```
cls && @echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 
set "_tag_00=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aiHqRt-mqxo"
set "_tag_01=--ignore-errors --abort-on-error --ignore-config --flat-playlist --geo-bypass "
set "_tag_02=--restrict-filenames --no-part --no-cache-dir --write-thumbnail --prefer-ffmpeg "
set "_tag_03=--ffmpeg-location .\ --postprocessor-args  -i "%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" -vf fps^=fps^=60^,"
set "_tag_04=scale^=1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -b:v 500k -preset superfast -c:a copy -f segment -segment_time "
set "_tag_05=60 %%^(title^)s.mp4"

youtube-dl "!_tag_00!" -f "bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best" -o "%%^(title^)s.%%^(ext^)s" !_tag_1!!_tag_2!!_tag_3!!_tag_4!!_tag_5!
Pause
```

Код 2 (с разбиением по длительности)

```
cls && @echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 

    :: do some with the bat file, after then,  for all links need `call :_yd_dl` %1

    call :_yd_dl %1
    echo/ is done^^!!

    goto :eof

    :_yd_dl

    set "_tag_00=https://www.twitch.tv/ninja"
    set "_tag_01= -t 00:60:00 -v error -stats -vf fps=fps=60,scale=1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -preset superfast -c:a copy "
    for /f %%i in ('.\youtube-dl.exe -g !_tag_00! ^<nul ') do .\ffmpeg.exe  -i "%%i" !_tag_01! .\output.mp4
    exit /b
```

**UPDATE** Написал скрипт

```
def refactor(second):
    if str(second)[0] == "-":
        number_sign = "-"
        second = int(str(second)[1:])
    else:
        number_sign = ""
    current_hours = str(second // 3600)
    remainder_second = second % 3600

    current_minutes = str(remainder_second // 60)
    current_seconds = str(remainder_second % 60)
    if len(current_hours) == 1:
        current_hours = "0" + current_hours

    if len(current_minutes) == 1:
        current_minutes = "0" + current_minutes

    if len(current_seconds) == 1:
        current_seconds = "0" + current_seconds

    text_time = number_sign + current_hours + ":" + current_minutes + ":" + current_seconds

    return text_time


def run():
    duration = 60
    time_stream = 0
    print(refactor(time_stream))
    while True:
        current_time_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H.%M.%S_%d_%m_%Y")
        subprocess.call(["streamlink", "--hls-live-edge", "99999", "--hls-segment-threads", "10", "--ringbuffer-size", "1024M", "--hls-duration", refactor(duration), "--hls-start-offset", refactor(time_stream),"-o",  current_time_date + ".ts", "https://www.twitch.tv/csruhub", "best"])

        time_stream =+ duration

        time.sleep(10)
```

И он разбивает на участки, но проблема в том, что начинает то он вовремя, а вот завершает, только когда заканчивается сегмент.

Получается, что участки накладываются друг на друга. Поэтому вопрос пока актуальный

Comment: Как это `youtube-dl` заброшен, если последний коммит вчера?

Comment: @donRumata Странно, я просто нашел какой-то репозиторий с таким же названием, и у него было обновление в 2017 году. Видимо перепутал.
Но это не отменяет эту проблему. Добавил код от youtube dl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный скрипт записывает видео с трансляции в прямом эфире, разбивая на куски примерно по 10 минут (до конца текущего сегмента).

```
:loop

set day=%DATE:~0,2%
set month=%DATE:~3,2%
set year=%DATE:~6,4%

set hour=%TIME:~0,2%
set minute=%TIME:~3,2%
set second=%TIME:~6,2%

set YYYYMMDD=%day%_%month%_%year%_%hour%_%minute%_%second%

streamlink --hls-live-edge 99999 --hls-segment-threads 10 --ringbuffer-size 1024M https://www.twitch.tv/username best -O | ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -f segment -segment_time 600 -vcodec copy -acodec copy twitch_%YYYYMMDD%_%%05d.ts

goto loop
```